# Factorial function through recursion using R with Rcpp

Tags: r, recursion, rcpp, factorial

My basic question is why do the results differ for these four implementations of the factorial function and more specifically why do the functions start to differ for n=13?

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('   int facCpp(int n)
                {
                    if (n==0) return 1;
                    if (n==1) return 1;
                    return n*facCpp(n-1);
                }
            ')



cppFunction('   double fac2Cpp(int n)
                {
                    if (n==0) return 1;
                    if (n==1) return 1;
                    return n*fac2Cpp(n-1);
                }
            ')

cppFunction('   long int fac3Cpp(long int n)
                {
                    if (n==0) return 1;
                    if (n==1) return 1;
                    return n*fac3Cpp(n-1);
                }
            ')

c(factorial(12),prod(1:12),facCpp(12),fac2Cpp(12),fac3Cpp(12))
c(factorial(13),prod(1:13),facCpp(13),fac2Cpp(13),fac3Cpp(13))
c(factorial(20),prod(1:20),facCpp(20),fac2Cpp(20),fac3Cpp(20))
c(factorial(40),prod(1:40),facCpp(40),fac2Cpp(40),fac3Cpp(40))
```

I realize that the question is perhaps a duplicate since an answers is probably suggested here
[Rcpp, creating a dataframe with a vector of long long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558658/rcpp-creating-a-dataframe-with-a-vector-of-long-long) which also shows suggests why the functions start to differ for f(13)

```
2^31-1>facCpp(12)
#> [1] TRUE
2^31-1>13*facCpp(12)
#> [1] FALSE


c(factorial(12),prod(1:12),facCpp(12),fac2Cpp(12),fac3Cpp(12))
#>[1] 479001600 479001600 479001600 479001600 479001600
c(factorial(13),prod(1:13),facCpp(13),fac2Cpp(13),fac3Cpp(13))
#> [1] 6227020800 6227020800 1932053504 6227020800 1932053504
c(factorial(20),prod(1:20),facCpp(20),fac2Cpp(20),fac3Cpp(20))
#> [1]  2.432902e+18  2.432902e+18 -2.102133e+09  2.432902e+18 -2.102133e+09
```

Comment: 12! overflows neither an `int` nor a `long int`. 13! overflows an `int` but not a `long int`. 40! overflows both. What you're seeing is overflow in your C++ code.

Comment: @josilber thx for the answer that clears up the C++ related part. But if you run the code you will notice that fac3Cpp(13) also returns a wrong result. So my guess is that this is related to the Rcpp package not supporting `long int` hence fac3Cpp becomes the facCpp.

Comment: @user2055639 fac3Cpp(13) returns the correct result on my machine.  The C++ standard allows for this difference though.

Comment: Similarly to @Dason, `fac3Cpp(13)` gives the correct result on my computer. Please update your post with the output you're seeing to get help with the discrepancy you're seeing.

Comment: @Dason ad "fac3Cpp(13) returns the correct result on my machine" this puzzles me? "The C++ standard allows for this difference though." not sure I get what you are aiming at here?? I guess in the end I'm looking for a somewhat general working rule for when not to use `int`. So I guess that in general one can't be certain that `long int` would fix the problem. ... I will update my post with output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially doing this wrong.  See the R help page for factorial:

> ‘factorial(x)’ (x! for non-negative integer ‘x’) is defined to be
>   ‘gamma(x+1)’ and ‘lfactorial’ to be ‘lgamma(x+1)’.

You are not supposed to compute it this way.  Why?  Well look at this:

```
R> evalCpp("INT_MAX")
[1] 2147483647
R>
```

You will hit numerical overflow.  Hence the different algorithm as implemented eg in R's `factorial()` function which just does `gamma(x+1)`.  And you can do that in C++ too:

```
R> cppFunction('double myFac(int x) { return(R::gammafn(x+1.0)); }')
R> myFac(4)
[1] 24
R> myFac(12)
[1] 479001600
R> myFac(13)
[1] 6227020800
R> myFac(20)
[1] 2.4329e+18
R> myFac(40)
[1] 8.15915e+47
R>
```

Comment: @Eddelbuettel thx for the answer it is important to see the way you are supposed to do it. I wasn't really aiming at a correct implementation of the factorial as just fooling around to get goint using Rcpp. If you have any thoughts as to why using `long int` in fac3Cpp returns the wrong answer please don't hold back?

Comment: Didn't have time to look in detail, and would suspect some OS and compiler-version dependence there as we all know what the correct answer should be.  I'd set up algorithms such that you are *not* likely to get bitten by under- or overflow.  [ BTW: It is Eddelbuettel with two Ds ]

Comment: @user2055639 compare `evalCpp("LONG_MAX")` and `factorial(21)` -- you're still going to overflow past 20. `double` is able to store a much larger range of values.