# Generating a 20-digit number in R

Tags: r, random

I would like to generate a random 20-digit number using R.

My first attempt was to do

```
runif(1,10000000000000000000,9999999999999999999)
```

But this doesn't seem to work because R keeps rounding the 9999999999999999999 to 10000000000000000000.  It doesn't seem to accept a "9999" number until I go down to 15 digits:

```
> 9999999999999999999
[1] 10000000000000000000
> 999999999999999999
[1] 1000000000000000000
> 99999999999999999
[1] 100000000000000000
> 9999999999999999
[1] 10000000000000000
> 999999999999999
[1]  999999999999999
> 99999999999999
[1]  99999999999999
> 9999999999999
[1]  9999999999999
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can generate this number as a string:

```
paste( sample( 0:9, 20, replace=TRUE ), collapse="" )
# [1] "40910135645767200675"
```

Comment: almost, you forgot about the 0 in front: `paste(c(sample(1:9,1), sample( 0:9, 19, replace=TRUE )), collapse="")`

Comment: Depending on how this number will be used (say, a 20-digit PIN number), a leading zero may be acceptable.

Comment: it's explicitly spelled out in OP

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1)
sprintf("%20.0f",runif(1,1e19,1e20))
#[1] "33895779682788999168"
```

Comment: This may be platform-dependent, but it is too close from the precision of the machine: the last digit is always even...

Comment: At first I thought this was generating randomly, but when I do it on my machine, I see the same issue Vincent mentions where it is always even

Comment: The same thing happens for me. Wonder why the last number is always even?

Comment: this *is* curious - try `sprintf("%.0f",runif(1,1e29,1e30))` - the last 10 digits or so are always even

Comment: Floating point numbers are actually encoded in binary form, with a limited number of binary digits. If we exceed the limit, the last binary digits are deemed non-significant: they are not stored, and assumed to be zero. Numbers ending with 0 in binary are multiples of 2, numbers ending in 00 multiples of 4, etc.

Comment: Apparently, it has to round even before the sprintf is done...looking at `print(runif(1,1e19,1e20),digits=22)`. Here's what I dug out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r

Comment: The classical reference for those problems is: 
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html).