# Scientific notation issue in R

Tags: r

I have an ID variable with 20 digits. Once i read the data in R , it changes to Scientific notation and then if i write the same id to csv file, the value of ID changes.

For example , running the below code should print me the value of x as "**12345678912345678912**",but it prints "**12345678912345679872**":

**Code:**

```
options(scipen=999)

x <- 12345678912345678912
```

print(x)

**Output:**

```
[1] 12345678912345679872
```

My questions are :

1) Why it is happening ?

2) How to fix this problem ?

I know it has to do with the storage of data types in R but still i think there should be some way to deal with this problem. I hope i am clear with this question.

I don't know if this question was asked or not in so point me to a link if its a duplicate.I will remove this post

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal), so i can relate with the issue of mine, but i am unable to fix it.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why don't you format your variable as character ?

Comment: Thanks for replying,The problem persists, if i use as.character(x) , the value of x is again "12345678912345679872"

Comment: I meant to format it "previously", like when you import your data, you can specify character colClasses for ID variable (so kind of doing x<-"12345678912345678912"). Would this work ?

Comment: else, you maybe can specify a larger number of digits with `options(digits=30)` for example ?

Comment: The number is to big to be represented as an integer. Thus, it is represented as a double, which leads to [issues with floating point number accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal). There are [possibilities to use big integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r) in R, but since your numbers are ids you should follow CathG's advice and treat them as character strings.

Comment: @CathG Yes it works, This is how i am doing it now: read.csv("file.csv",colClasses=c("character",rep(NULL,1))) as i have only two columns (ID and value). Thanks , By the way you can put your thought as answer, I would love to accept your answer.

Comment: ok great. I'm guessing you're second column is numeric ? so you can rather do colClasses=c("character","numeric") (by the way, no need to use `rep` if you're repeating just once ;-) )

Comment: Thanks @CathG , you can put your thoughts as an answer, It would be helpful to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To circumvent the problem due to number storing/representation, you can import your `ID` variable directly as character with the option `colClasses`, for example, if using `read.csv` and importing a data.frame with the `ÌD` column and another numeric column:

```
mydata<-read.csv("file.csv",colClasses=c("character","numeric"),...)
```

Answer (score 3):

R does not by default handle integers numerically larger than `2147483647L`.

If you append an `L` to your number (to tell R its an `integer`), you get:

```
x <- 12345678912345678912L
#Warning message:
#non-integer value 12345678912345678912L qualified with L; using numeric value
```

This also explains the change of the last digits as R stores the number as a `double`.

I think the `gmp`-package should be able to handle large numbers in general. You should therefore either accept the loss of precision, store them as character stings, or use a data-type from the `gmp` package.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views and knowhow of gmp package.

Answer (score 1):

Using `readr` you can do

```
mydata <- readr::read_csv("file.csv", col_types = list(ID=col_character()))
```

where "ID" is the name of your ID column