# How to force fromJSON from jsonlite to read numbers as characters

Tags: json, r

I have a bunch of keys in a JSON file that are defined by numbers like 8374829806766627074.

When I try to read them in R I get completely different numbers. For instance, 8374829806766627074 becomes 8374829806766626816.

I am using the fromJSON in the jsonlite package to read a json file from citrix api.

How can I instead adjust the function to read numbers as characters. I seem to fail finding a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: You have to read characters without converting to numbers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: @jogo That question deals with floating point numbers, which, in my opinion, isn't directly applicable here. I think in this instance, it's more likely to deal with OP's `digits` option and the fact that the number is bouncing up against [the largest number that can be represented in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807). But I do agree that the number should be read in as a character string and not a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long Numbers As A Character String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339636/long-numbers-as-a-character-string)

Comment: @jogo Do you know how to force fromJSON to read numbers as characters? Maybe this is the only solution to that.

Comment: @brittenbThen eventually the number is not get as longint and because it don't fit to the shorter integer it is handled as double ... .

Comment: @boyansky Sorry, I have no experience in JSON. One simple method can be put a letter in front of the key: k8374829806766627074 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919403/scientific-notation-issue-in-r the answer from AEBilgrau is interesting, so you can try `x <- 8374829806766627074L` Beside of this the relative different of the two numbers seems to be near the machine-eps.

Comment: @brittenb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919403/scientific-notation-issue-in-r the answer from AEBilgrau is interesting. So the value mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807 is a theoretical value. The implementation in a progrmming language can differ from the theoretical value.

Comment: @jogo Thanks for the link. Definitely good information to have.

Comment: Was there ever any resolution to the core question to *"how to force fromJSON ..."*? Appending `L` or prepending some character or manually adding quotes is missing the (clear) point of how to do it _programmatically_. The `jsonlite::fromJSON` function lacks arguments that might help, such as `as.is=TRUE` or `colClasses="character"` (borrowed from other functions for demonstration, clearly they don't work here).

Comment: For instance, if external programs are allowed, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504448/176511 might be a start, though it does not recurse.