# how to convert 20 digits character to numeric

Tags: r, integer, numeric

I have four 20 digits characters.
I want to convert characters to numeric.
I just converted using as.numeric function.
But four characters all same.
Why?
I need numeric. Is there a way?

```
tmp <- c("11240690100051000001", "11240690100051000002", "11240690100051000003", "11240690100051000004")
tmp1 <- as.numeric(tmp)

tmp1[1] == tmp1[2]
[1] TRUE
tmp1[1] == tmp1[3]
[1] TRUE
tmp1[1] == tmp1[4]
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This discussion might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-digits-in-r

Comment: I think you might have hit the limit of numerical precision in R, hence all the numbers are close enough that they are 'equal', e.g. `1.0000000000000001==1`

Comment: Conversion to scalars (with `as.numeric()`) hits the precion wall. Adding the digits does not rectify the situation. And converting into integers does not work either. If you need to store large integers, please see the package Brobgingnag and this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r.

Comment: I mean package Brobdingnag. Typing it about 10 times makes it perfect...

Comment: `library("int64")` helps a little bit, but not enough: `as.int64("1000000000000000000")` works, but not one more digit

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Rmpfr` package:

```
tmp <- c("11240690100051000001", 
 "11240690100051000002", "11240690100051000003", 
"11240690100051000004")
library("Rmpfr")
as.bigz(tmp)
##  Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 4:
## [1] 11240690100051000001 11240690100051000002 11240690100051000003
## [4] 11240690100051000004
```

... but this may limit severely what you can subsequently do with these values.  More context in the question about why you need these as numeric/what you plan to do with them might give lead to more helpful answers ...