# Increasing the size of a double in R

Tags: r, double, bioconductor

I am importing a large fcs file (flow cytometry) into R.

when looking at the values for one of the columns, I notice that all the high values are squashed to  262144.0 ( = 2^18). Is there a way I can tell R to use longer bits for its doubles?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r

Comment: This is a question for the `maintainer()` of the package you are using to read the data, or perhaps the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org) -- R does not have a problem with values greater than 2^18, as evidenced by the output of `.Machine$double.xmax`.