# Is there way to change the column type long to double in SparkR dataframe

Tags: ibm-cloud, apache-spark-sql, cloudant

Is there way to change the column type long to double in SparkR dataframe. I have a SparkR dataframe "dataDF" with three columns col1(long), col2(double), col3(double) which is format cloudant database. I want to change the type "long" to "double" for the col1 in SparkR dataframe "dataDF". Kindly let me know how to do it? I am using Spark R notebook. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`as.double()` should work, but this topic is discussed more at [long/bigint/decimal equivalent datatype in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r)