# Importing large numbers when binding csv files

Tags: r, readr

Having trouble with my code while trying to import my data with a column that exceeds the maximum integer (.Machine$integer.max = 2147483647). Using readr's read_csv I believe it's importing as NA instead of rounding off. The complication comes from trying to import multiple csvs with rbindlist.

Here is my current setup:

```
 load_df_path <- file.path(".../dffolder") #path to folder
 df_path_files <- list.files <- (load_df_path, full.names = TRUE) #list files in path

 df <- rbindlist(lapply(df_path_files, read_csv)) # read in csvs using readr
```

How do I write the last line to import the csvs and turn the column "amount" to characters instead of integers?

Here are a few things I tried without any luck...

```
## This gets error: Error in switch(tools::file_ext(path)....
 df <- rbindlist(lapply(df_path_files, read_csv(df_path_files, col_types = list(amount = col_character())))) 


## recreate read_csv and changed col_types = NULL to the above but getting the warning
## Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : could not find function "read_delimited"
```

tl;dr - need help importing a list of csvs while changing specific column to character format or an int64.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just the syntax...

```
df_list <- lapply(df_path_files, read_csv, col_types = cols(amount = col_character()))
df <- rbindlist(df_list)
```

`col_types` expects `NULL` or something created by `cols`. See `?read_csv` and `?cols`.

One other idea: Maybe enforcing `numeric` instead of `int` could be a solution: Using `cols(amount = col_double())`
See here:
[long/bigint/decimal equivalent datatype in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r)

Comment: Thank you for the syntax fix! I'll take a look at using numeric!