# How to make R more precise?

Tags: r

When I plug these equations into R I get:

```
> 1/(1+exp(-18))
[1] 1
> 1/(1+exp(-16))
[1] 0.9999999
```

But when I plug the same equations into Chrome I get:

```
1/(1+exp(-18))
0.99999998477 

1/(1+exp(-16))
0.99999988746
```

So it seems like R is not very precise and rounds numbers up. Is it possible for me to get more digit precision with R? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r

Comment: Type `options(digits= 11)` and recompute.  R just does not display so many digits by default.

Comment: ohhhh thank-you! that's what i needed!

Comment: or `print(1/(1+exp(-18)), digits = 11)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user G5W, I realized I needed to do:

```
options(digits=11)
```

And rerun my `exp()` equations. B/c by default R does not display so many digits.