# R is changing my variable value by itself

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, output, precision

I have a dataframe that has an `id` field with values as these two:

```
587739706883375310

587739706883375408
```

The problem is that, when I ask R to show these two numbers, the output that I get is the following:

```
587739706883375360

587739706883375360
```

which are not the *real* values of my `ID` field, how do I solve that?

For your information: I have executed `options(scipen = 999)` to R does not convert my number to a scientific notation.
This problem also happens in R console, if I enter these examples numbers I also get the same printing as shown above.

EDIT: someone asked

```
dput(yourdata$id)
```

I did that and the result was:

```
c(587739706883375360, 587739706883375360, 587739706883375488, 587739706883506560, 587739706883637632, 587739706883637632, 587739706883703040)
```

To compare, the original data in the csv file is:

```
587739706883375310,587739706883375408,587739706883375450,587739706883506509,587739706883637600,587739706883637629,587739706883703070
```

I also did the following test with one of these numbers:

```
> 587739706883375408
[1] 587739706883375360
> as.double(587739706883375408)
[1] 587739706883375360
> class(as.double(587739706883375408))
[1] "numeric"
> is.double(as.double(587739706883375408))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Please dput(yourdata$id).

Comment: Use a big int formula or (probably more appropriate) read the column in as a character column. Unless you're doing math with these numbers, treating them as character is probably best.

Comment: This is a common problem with computers trying to emulate numbers. R by default (like many other languages) saves numbers in double-precision. This means that it can only save the first 16 digits of a number - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [long/bigint/decimal equivalent datatype in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [bit64](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bit64) package to represent such large numbers:

```
library(bit64)
as.integer64("587739706883375408")
# integer64
# [1] 587739706883375408
as.integer64("587739706883375408") + 1 
# integer64
# [1] 587739706883375409
```