# Different number while converting from string to double in R

Tags: r

On R 3.5.2 and while trying to convert string to double, the output is wrong,

```
# this is just to avoid scientific notation. 
options(scipen=999)

temp <- "2671768011130961018032700237"
as.numeric(temp)
# and the output is, 
2671768011130961013860062868

as.double(temp)
# and the output is 
2671768011130961013860062868

as.numeric(temp) == 2671768011130961018032700237
# this returns true

print(.Machine$double.xmax)
# and to check the overflow case, this prints out 179769313486231570838400602864442228000008602082842266064064680402680408280648240046204888888288080622822420842246006644866884860462806420066668022046626024066662068886808602862886866800048228686262462640668044406484606206082824406288200264266406808068464046840608044222802268424008466606886862062820068082688
```

Can't think of anything which could have cause this behaviour. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a double precision issue. Double precise numbers have roughly 15 digits of accuracy. Beyond that, there is no guarantee that arithmetic will be accurate to your most significant digit.

Comment: You don't even need the double converstion: `> 2671768011130961018032700237
[1] 2671768011130961013860062868`

Comment: Indeed. I don't understand what that strange xmax value is because that would not fit a double.

Comment: If you need better than double precision, use high precision numbers: `library(Rmpfr); mpfr(temp, 256)`

Comment: You should read this section from Wikipedia: [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). Basically, you have 53 bits of precision and when converted to base 10 gives: log10(2^53 - 1) = 15.95459

Comment: The problem here is with `options(sicpen = 999)` giving the illusion that you are getting those digits accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that the following equality comparison is also returning `TRUE`:

```
as.numeric(temp) == 2671768011130961013860062868
[1] TRUE
```

The short answer here is the double/float precision in R, and most other programming languages, is not exact.  Both of the following two comparisons return `TRUE`:

```
as.numeric(temp) == 2671768011130961018032700237
as.numeric(temp) == 2671768011130961013860062868
```

What is likely happening here is that R is only comparing up to a certain significant figure, and both numbers on the RHS are close enough that the comparison appears `TRUE` in both cases.

If you are looking for a "fix" here, then what you need to use is an exact numeric type, such as integer.  The problem with integer is that your values are too large to be stored, so what you really need is the equivalent of `long` in other languages such as Java.  Base R does not seem to support this, but if you [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r) then you might find a few custom R packages which support things like `int64`.

Comment: Fun game: `2671768011130961018032700237+500000==2671768011130961018032700237 [1] TRUE`

Comment: Just to clarify. R uses `long int` for integers as defined in `C` which uses 4 bytes. The equivalent of what you are referring to (I.e. `long` in Java) would be a `long long int` or `int64_t` as defined in `<stdint.h>`. Also, this still would not help in this case as the numbers are well beyond the precision of these data types (roughly 19 decimal digits). The only sensible solution would be to use `gmp` or `Rmpfr`.

Comment: @JosephWood Well that was a `long` comment, but thanks for clarifying.