# R Changing Data Values when using dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I am adding data to R by creating a vector of IDs (1,430 IDs to be exact) and when I save it as a dataframe, not only do some of the IDs disappear but new IDs appear that do not exist. My code is below but, for example, when I search data frame A for ID '58015666070300012501' it says there is no match (even though this is included in myid). And now in A there is ID '116151666070400008192' that does not exist in the myid column. I have saved myid as a string and resplit it, saved it as numeric, etc, and the same thing is still happening. Why would this occur? And how can I prevent it?

```
#Code
options(scipen=999)
myid <- factor(c(1714,1702 , 1706, 1721, 173, 1723, 
      1711, 1741, 1715, 1729, 1736, 10000000705,
      1724, 1722, 1717, 1709, 1726,171,
      1731, 1738,160516660823 , 1708, 1713, 1701, 
      1727, 16061666070110000401,160616660801,1704 , 170410000101,
      2746,2714, 2703, 2704 , 2705, 2713,
      2715, 2706, 2707, 2717, 2732,
      3729,380000000749, 38000000075,380000000761   , 380116660722, 380000000731,
      380000000747,
      46062666070200001901,460626660801, 4726, 472, 4732,4721,
      4722, 4723, 4702,4703, 4705, 4706,
      4707, 4708, 4709, 471,4711, 4712, 
      4713, 4714,4716, 4724, 4725, 380000000751,
      380000000768,3727, 38000000076100001401, 38000000076, 380000000728, 360076660745,
      360076660801, 3701, 3705, 371, 3712, 3714,
      3719, 3721, 3723, 375, 380000000734,360056660824,
      3704, 360106660702, 36010666070210001201, 360106660801,3713,
      5743,580000000799922, 5764, 5748, 5765, 560246660715, 56024666071600002701,
      580000000797, 580000000779, 5769, 5719, 5737, 5758, 5799911,
      5766, 58015666072, 5799906, 5705, 5724, 5757, 5799913, 
      5799912, 5755, 5799926, 5706, 5759, 5718, 571112, 
      5799908, 5799928, 56001666070400002401, 560016660802, 5771, 5713, 573, 
      5734, 572, 5728, 576, 560186660715, 56018666071600002601, 5799907,
      575, 5708, 5726, 57013, 5745, 5799909,577,
      5800000007998,56042666071500002901, 560426660801, 560426660814, 5601966608144, 
      5723,5742,57014,580000000799923, 580000000799924, 560106660701, 56010666070200002501,
      5716,57015,5704,5739, 5768 ,5736, 5727, 5702, 
      5756,5799927,580000000799902, 5753, 580000000799938, 57012, 571,
      5703, 57011, 5738, 5799931, 5707, 5746, 5799919,
      5717, 5752, 5763, 5701, 5722, 579992, 5799932,
      58015666070300012501, 5712, 5709, 5711, 5799914, 579991, 560366660732, 
      5714, 5799905, 5772, 5799903,
      680000000788, 680000000732, 6703, 6701, 6702, 6704, 6705, 
      6706, 6707, 6712, 6715, 6716, 6717, 6718, 
      6719, 672, 6723, 6724, 6727, 6733, 6734, 
      680000000799, 660226660706, 660226660803, 660226660804, 660226660805, 660036660702, 660036660801, 
      680000000722, 680000000731, 6772, 680000000734, 6785, 680000000729,
      760016660708,7600166608078, 7701, 7702, 7712, 7707, 771, 
      7715, 7724, 7703, 7705, 7727, 7711,773, 
      7709, 7728, 7719, 7725, 7729,
      8705, 871, 8703, 8715, 8702, 8701, 8706, 8708,
      10707, 1071, 1071011004701, 10751, 10712, 10798, 107992, 107602, 
      1076040006101, 10797, 1079710007101, 10715, 1071520005202, 107994, 107589, 107997,
      1079991, 10744, 107607, 10716, 1060606660703, 1060606660704, 106060666070500008701, 1060606660801,
      1060606660802, 1079999108001, 10735, 10701, 1070110004501,10757, 10778, 1077810006501, 
      107996,1079961007501, 10785, 10737, 10711, 107588, 1074, 10782,
      10748, 10733, 10764, 10706, 10783, 1080000000761, 10800000007584, 1079110007001,
      10791, 10765, 1076520004809, 10723, 1072310005601, 108000000079881, 10718, 1078110008401,
      10714,10799997,10799, 107999, 1060326660702, 1060326660801, 1078610006801, 1060136660802,
      106013666070400008501,10754,10788,1079993, 10799992, 1079999408101, 107601, 108000000079996,
      10800000007582,1079995, 10800000007587, 10789, 107101, 10755, 1078330006703, 10758,
      108000000079997, 10709, 10739, 1060176660801, 10763, 107103, 1071031005001, 1077,
      10800000007585,107102, 10725, 10702,1072010005501, 10792, 10708,10769, 
      1076910006301, 10717,10762,10719,1071910005401,10796, 10800000007586,1072,
      1060376660801,10768,1080000000799994,10753,10779,1078000006601,10713,107109,
      10795,107998,10705,
      1178,11751, 11782, 1180000000758, 1171720009402, 11703, 1176510008802,
      1176520008803, 1179971, 11799991, 116060666070200010601, 1160606660801, 11729,1179,
      1179941,117991, 11799711,1171710009401,11765, 11763, 11714,
      11776, 11764, 1179921, 11799411, 11778,1175410010501, 11709,
      11772, 11746, 117993, 1179981, 118000000076,11734, 11786,
      1179997, 11708, 11744,1179961, 11728, 1179998, 11704, 
      11726, 1173, 11733, 11711,11777, 11754, 11745, 
      11702, 11766, 1179999, 116151666070300010701, 116151666070400010702, 1161516660801,11799211,
      117997, 1179996, 11712,1179911 , 11799811, 1177810010002, 11791,
      118134666079981, 11752, 11774, 11713, 11799611,1180000000757, 11743,
      1175, 11731, 11707, 117995, 11796, 1174, 11799311, 
      1175110010301, 1179951, 11738, 11753,11735, 1177110009802, 11755,
      12701 ,12703, 12704, 12702, 12708, 12705, 12706, 12707,
      13701, 13707, 13708, 13709, 13702, 13705, 13713,
      13715, 1380000000717, 1380000000718, 13706,13711, 13712,
      14712, 14745, 14716, 14736, 14725, 14756, 1480000000755,
      14738, 1480000000766,14739,14757, 1471, 14727, 14751,
      14746, 146003666071, 1460036660809, 1473, 14748, 14731, 14721, 
      14723,14706 , 14732, 14749, 1461006660707, 1461006660806, 14744, 
      1460906660808, 14741, 14705, 14747, 14752, 14709, 14753, 
      14708, 14707,
      1573, 15719,1571, 15711, 15738, 1580000000739, 158000000074, 
      1580000000741, 15704, 15707, 15709, 1572, 156084666070600004701, 1560846660805,
      15705,
      16708, 16728,16711,16724, 16732, 16726,1671 ,
      16725, 16744, 1680000000731, 16721, 16701, 16709, 16733,
      16716, 16705, 1674100012201   , 16704, 16729, 16703, 16734, 
      16727, 16713, 1672,
      17714, 17703, 17702, 17718, 1760526660703, 1760526660802, 
      1780526660722, 17712, 178000000072,
      18601066607074, 18601066608073, 1880000000719, 18709, 1860806660702, 186080666070300013201,
      18702,1871,18711, 1860346660714,1860346660813, 1860266660752, 1860266660851 ,
      18706, 1860746660711, 186074666071200013101   , 1880000000714, 18713, 1880000000726,
      19701,19702,19703 , 19704, 19705, 19707   , 19711 ,
      19712, 19713,1980000000714, 1980000000733, 19736, 1980000000734, 1980000000738, 
      1980000000737,1980000000731,1980000000736, 1980000000739 , 1980000000742, 19727,198000000072,
      1980000000721,1980000000735, 19739, 1980000000732, 1960026660801, 1980000000741,1980000000743,
      1960226660705,196022666070600013301 , 1960226660707, 19731, 1980000000728, 198000000074, 1980000000727,
      1973, 19734, 19735, 198000000073, 19732, 1980000000729, 19737,
      208000000071, 20708, 20704, 20705, 20706, 20707, 2071,
      218000000074, 2171, 2160016660702, 2160016660801, 21703, 21704,
      21701,21705, 21706, 21726 , 21733, 21714, 
      21724, 21728,
      226017666070200014001,22725 , 22728, 22716, 2260176660801,22701, 
      22719, 22722, 22707, 22718, 22729, 2273,
      22708, 22709, 22702, 22704, 2280000000737,
      23756, 23779, 23788,23781, 23759, 23705,
       23748, 23749, 23784, 23786, 23782, 23785, 
       23704, 23712,237121,23752, 23764, 2379, 
       23701, 2376, 23751, 23761,23714  , 23789, 
       23715, 2360816660815, 2372, 2378, 23711, 23765, 
       23757, 23783,2375 , 23799, 23776, 23721, 
       237441,
      2480000000709991, 2460696660801,2480000000727,24726, 24711, 2460556660801, 
      248000000073,2480626660726, 2460586660817, 24701,24702, 24703,
      24704,24705, 2471,24712, 24713, 24714, 
      2460816660801,24725,
      25718,25741, 25736, 25742, 25724, 25734, 
      25729, 25726,25743, 25722, 2580000000735, 25714, ###
      25703,2580000000731, 2574, 25702,25713, 25723,
      25727, 25745, 25746,  25716, 25735, 25705, 
      25719, 2580000000737, 258001666071, 25701, 25709, 25717, 
      25721, 25715, 258000000074, 25744 , 2580000000741, 25725, 
      2580000000736, 2572, 2560826660701, 256082666070300014601, 2560826660801,
      2674, 26713, 26717, 26711, 26705, 26715,
      26722, 26701,26703, 26706, 26708, 26702,
      2671, 2660396660855,26724,  2673, 26709, 26728,
      26731,
      2780000000706,278000000074,2780000000708, 27711, 2780000000738, 
      2780000000709, 2780000000737, 27701,2780000000704, 278000000070991,
      28704, 28707, 2871, 28711, 28712, 28715,28714, 28713,
      29709, 2971, 2973400014802, 29704, 298000000073, 29714,
      30701, 30708, 30709, 30705, 30706,30703,
      31707, 31705, 31708, 31714, 31704,31713,
      316006666070200015701,3160066660801, 316003666070300015601, 3160036660802, 31718, 31719,
      31716,31712, 31702, 3171, 31706,
      32709, 3280000000713,32706,3280000000716, 3271300015901, 32708,
      32702, 32707, 327071, 327073, 3280000000714, 32701, 
      32715, 32716, 3280000000715,
      33703,33702, 33704, 33726, 3372,33762,
      33729,3380316660702, 3380316660704 , 3376, 33774, 33707, 
      33756, 33751, 33737, 33735, 33755, 33701, 
      33718, 33749, 33764, 33721, 3373, 33731,
      33742, 3374, 3371, 3360366660703, 3360366660801, 3360166660801,
      33723, 33728, 33715, 33712, 33724, 33709, 
      33754, 33717, 33741, 33719,
      34761, 34723, 34791, 347447, 3479997, 34789,
      34746, 34732, 34713, 34603966608076, 34603966608074, 34603966607075,
      34603966607077, 34603966607078, 3478, 34772, 34769, 34745,
      34711, 3460966660801, 347101, 34716, 34754, 34724,
      34736, 34782, 34722, 34704, 3471, 3471994,
      34756, 347993, 34779, 34771, 347102, 34751,
      347103,34719, 34786, 34787, 3476, 34776,
      34717, 34784, 34766, 34767, 34729, 34747,
      34702,34798, 34742, 34783, 34788, 34738,
      34768, 34734, 34727, 3471991, 3479996, 347446,
      34703,34796, 34785, 34753 , 34715, 34718,
      34758, 3480466660791111, 34755, 347992,
      35701, 35702, 35703, 3580000000717,3580456660714, 3580000000713,
      3580000000715,35713, 3580000000716 , 35712,
      3680000000754,36737, 3671, 36728, 36725, 36731, 
      3680000000742, 36723, 36736, 366015666070200016401, 3660156660801, 36727,
      3680000000741, 36717, 36732, 36703, 36729, 36735,
      36702,3673,36706 , 36734, 36716, 36718, 
      36733, 36738, 3680000000739,
      37743, 37706, 37724, 3780000000749, 3760096660709, 3760096660808,
      37717, 3780000000791, 37728, 37731, 37701, 37725,
      3780000000747, 37735, 37708, 10003586, 3780000000748,37718 ,
      37745,37709, 3780000000761, 37707, 37729, 37738,
      3772,37721, 378000000076, 37723, 3780000000793, 3760556660701,
      376055666070100016908, 37712, 37714, 37716, 37785, 37786,
      37787,3780000000755, 3780000000789, 3780000000792, 37702, 3780000000758,
      37704, 37726, 37727, 3780000000754, 37788, 37742, 
      378000000075,
      38765, 38719, 38722, 38763,38721, 38716,
      3872, 38701, 3860366660702, 3860366660801, 38705, 38723,
      38764,
      39777, 39778, 39701, 39702, 39703, 39704,
      39705, 39706, 39707, 39708, 39709, 39711,
      39713, 39714, 39718, 39719, 3972, 39722, 
      39723, 39724,39727, 39728, 39729, 3973,
      39731, 39732, 39733, 39734, 39735,39736, 
      39737, 39738, 39739, 3974, 39741, 39775,
      3980000000742,39742, 39766 , 39776, 3960426660702,3960426660801,
      3960606660704 , 3960606660803, 3960116660702, 3960116660801, 39763,3960546660728,
      3960546660827, 39771, 3980000000757, 3980000000787, 3980356660765, 3977,
      39800000007768, 3980000000794, 3980000000788, 3960646660704, 3960646660704000177,396064666070500017701,
      39769, 3960606660828, 3960606660829, 396060666083, 39779,
      40702, 40703, 40704, 40708,40709 , 4071, 40705, 4071300017801,
      4160356660703, 416035666070400018101, 41702, 41708, 41709, 41713,
      41736, 416019666070300017901, 4160196660802, 41734, 4160256660702, 4160256660801,
      41738, 41701, 41717, 41728, 41748, 41716,
      42701, 42703, 42704, 4280000000705, 4270800017902, 4270700017901,
      4260676660801, 4270800018001,
      4380000000723, 4360796660715, 43607966608142, 43702, 43703, 43704,
      43705, 43713, 43716, 43719, 4372, 43721,
      43722, 43724, 4380000000735, 4380000000737,
      44752,44729, 44778, 44706, 4460716660708, 446071666070900018902,
      44607166608076, 4460116660702, 4460116660801, 446123666071700019101, 4461236660814, 4461236660815,
      4461236660816, 44762, 4475, 4481146660702, 4461146660701, 4461146660803,
      44799987, 44703, 44781, 4480000000736, 4480000000799967, 448000000078092,
      4480000000799952, 4477, 4460216660801, 44701999, 44764, 44783,
      44759, 448000000078032, 44731, 44774, 44800000007994, 4479994,
      44746,4480486660701, 44775, 4462206660714, 4462206660813, 44800000007996,
      4462206660811, 44723, 44709, 44721,44733, 4479998, 
      44814766607918, 448000000078041, 44756, 4480000000798005, 44756, 44772,
      44758,44798004, 44705,44711, 44712, 44715, 
      44716,44757,  4476,44766, 44767, 44769,
      44777,44779, 44782, 44785, 44787, 44788, 
      44789, 44791, 44793, 44794,44795, 44796,
      44798001, 44798003, 4479995, 44799961, 44799962, 44799963,
      4480000000737,44800000007993, 448000000079996, 448000000079997,448000000079999,4480000000799992,
      44800000007998,44799991, 44761, 4480000000799995, 44765, 4480000000738,
      44753, 44755,4480000000792, 4480000000799885, 44714, 4479993,
      440000000776,44732, 44713, 4480000000741,44725 , 44726, 
      44784,4472,44749, 4481956660701 , 44800000007802, 44797,
      44808566607511, 44824566607914,44717, 44724, 44707, 44708, 
      44727, 44771, 44799992, 44768, 4460716660701, 4460576660818,
      4473,448000000079991, 44704 , 4480000000799993, 44748, 44719,
      44745, 4460196660723,4460196660822, 4461496660713, 4461496660812, 4480000000739, 
      44773,44734,
      4580000000714,45706 , 45712, 4580186660701,
      46705, 46701, 46702,46704, 46706, 46707 , 
      46708, 4671,
      47794,47792, 476124666071, 476124666071100020401, 478000000079, 4760536660712,
      476053666071300020501,4761246660709, 4761246660809, 47703 , 47705,47706,
      47707,47708, 47709 , 4771,47711, 47714 ,
      47716, 47717, 4772, 47721, 47724, 47728,
      4773, 47731,47732, 47733, 47736, 47738,
      47739, 4774,47743 , 47744, 47745, 47747,
      47749, 477491, 4775, 47751, 47754, 47755,
      47756,47757 , 47758, 47759, 4776, 47761,
      47762,47763, 477631, 47764, 47765, 47766,
      47767, 47768, 47773,47774,47775,47784,
      47785, 47786,47787, 4779,4780000000785,
      48722, 48781, 48706, 48705, 48713, 48707,
      48732, 48711, 48726, 48703, 48714,48777,
      48704, 48779,
      4960326660807,4960416660709, 4960416660808, 4960396660708,496039666071,496039666071100021001,
      4960116660709, 496011666071000020901,4960316660801, 49714, 49713, 49719,
      4960246660713,496024666071400021101, 49718, 49716, 49703,
      50707, 50739, 50743, 50704,50703, 50702,
      50714,50715 , 50716, 50718, 5060396660717, 5060396660816,
      50738,50747, 50733 , 50723,
      51704,5170500021501 , 51701))

a <- as.data.frame(myid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would this occur?

The problem is that your ID values are too large to be handled as numerical variables or as integers. The numeric values in R can only hold 16 significant digest:

```r
-log10(.Machine$double.eps)
#R> [1] 15.65356
```

The largest integer is:

```r
.Machine$integer.max
#R> 2147483647
```

If I create an array like you:

```r
myid_num <- c(1714, 1702, 1706, 1721, 173, 1723, 1711, 1741, 1715, 1729, 1736, 10000000705, 1724, 1722, 1717, 1709, 1726, 171, 1731, 1738, 160516660823, 1708, 1713, 1701, 1727, 16061666070110000401, 160616660801, 1704, 170410000101, 2746, 2714, 2703, 2704, 2705, 2713, 2715, 2706, 2707, 2717, 2732, 3729, 380000000749, 38000000075, 380000000761, 380116660722, 380000000731, 380000000747, 46062666070200001901, 460626660801, 4726, 472, 4732, 4721, 4722, 4723, 4702, 4703, 4705, 4706, 4707, 4708, 4709, 471, 4711, 4712, 4713, 4714, 4716, 4724, 4725, 380000000751, 380000000768, 3727, 38000000076100001401, 38000000076, 380000000728, 360076660745, 360076660801, 3701, 3705, 371, 3712, 3714, 3719, 3721, 3723, 375, 380000000734, 360056660824, 3704, 360106660702, 36010666070210001201, 360106660801, 3713, 5743, 580000000799922, 5764, 5748, 5765, 560246660715, 56024666071600002701, 580000000797, 580000000779, 5769, 5719, 5737, 5758, 5799911, 5766, 58015666072, 5799906, 5705, 5724, 5757, 5799913, 5799912, 5755, 5799926, 5706, 5759, 5718, 571112, 5799908, 5799928, 56001666070400002401, 560016660802, 5771, 5713, 573, 5734, 572, 5728, 576, 560186660715, 56018666071600002601, 5799907, 575, 5708, 5726, 57013, 5745, 5799909, 577, 5800000007998, 56042666071500002901, 560426660801, 560426660814, 5601966608144, 5723, 5742, 57014, 580000000799923, 580000000799924, 560106660701, 56010666070200002501, 5716, 57015, 5704, 5739, 5768 ,5736, 5727, 5702, 5756, 5799927, 580000000799902, 5753, 580000000799938, 57012, 571, 5703, 57011, 5738, 5799931, 5707, 5746, 5799919, 5717, 5752, 5763, 5701, 5722, 579992, 5799932, 58015666070300012501, 5712, 5709, 5711, 5799914, 579991, 560366660732, 5714, 5799905, 5772, 5799903, 680000000788, 680000000732, 6703, 6701, 6702, 6704, 6705, 6706, 6707, 6712, 6715, 6716, 6717, 6718, 6719, 672, 6723, 6724, 6727, 6733, 6734, 680000000799, 660226660706, 660226660803, 660226660804, 660226660805, 660036660702, 660036660801, 680000000722, 680000000731, 6772, 680000000734, 6785, 
              680000000729, 760016660708, 7600166608078, 7701, 7702, 7712, 7707, 771, 7715, 7724, 7703, 7705, 7727, 7711, 773, 7709, 7728, 7719, 7725, 7729, 8705, 871, 8703, 8715, 8702, 8701, 8706, 8708, 10707, 1071, 1071011004701, 10751, 10712, 10798, 107992, 107602, 1076040006101, 10797, 1079710007101, 10715, 1071520005202, 107994, 107589, 107997, 1079991, 10744, 107607, 10716, 1060606660703, 1060606660704, 106060666070500008701, 1060606660801, 1060606660802, 1079999108001, 10735, 10701, 1070110004501, 10757, 10778, 1077810006501, 107996, 1079961007501, 10785, 10737, 10711, 107588, 1074, 10782, 10748, 10733, 10764, 10706, 10783, 1080000000761, 10800000007584, 1079110007001, 10791, 10765, 1076520004809, 10723, 1072310005601, 108000000079881, 10718, 1078110008401, 10714, 10799997, 10799, 107999, 1060326660702, 1060326660801, 1078610006801, 1060136660802, 106013666070400008501, 10754, 10788, 1079993, 10799992, 1079999408101, 107601, 108000000079996, 10800000007582, 1079995, 10800000007587, 10789, 107101, 10755, 1078330006703, 10758, 108000000079997, 10709, 10739, 1060176660801, 10763, 107103, 1071031005001, 1077, 10800000007585, 107102, 10725, 10702, 1072010005501, 10792, 10708, 10769, 1076910006301, 10717, 10762, 10719, 1071910005401, 10796, 10800000007586, 1072, 1060376660801, 10768, 1080000000799994, 10753, 10779, 1078000006601, 10713, 107109, 10795, 107998, 10705, 1178, 11751, 11782, 1180000000758, 1171720009402, 11703, 1176510008802, 1176520008803, 1179971, 11799991, 116060666070200010601, 1160606660801, 11729, 1179, 1179941, 117991, 11799711, 1171710009401, 11765, 11763, 11714, 11776, 11764, 1179921, 11799411, 11778, 1175410010501, 11709, 11772, 11746, 117993, 1179981, 118000000076, 11734, 11786, 1179997, 11708, 11744, 1179961, 11728, 1179998, 11704, 11726, 1173, 11733, 11711, 11777, 11754, 11745, 11702, 11766, 1179999, 116151666070300010701, 116151666070400010702, 1161516660801, 11799211, 117997, 1179996, 11712, 1179911, 11799811, 1177810010002, 11791, 
              118134666079981, 11752, 11774, 11713, 11799611, 1180000000757, 11743, 1175, 11731, 11707, 117995, 11796, 1174, 11799311, 1175110010301, 1179951, 11738, 11753, 11735, 1177110009802, 11755, 12701 ,12703, 12704, 12702, 12708, 12705, 12706, 12707, 13701, 13707, 13708, 13709, 13702, 13705, 13713, 13715, 1380000000717, 1380000000718, 13706, 13711, 13712, 14712, 14745, 14716, 14736, 14725, 14756, 1480000000755, 14738, 1480000000766, 14739, 14757, 1471, 14727, 14751, 14746, 146003666071, 1460036660809, 1473, 14748, 14731, 14721, 14723, 14706, 14732, 14749, 1461006660707, 1461006660806, 14744, 1460906660808, 14741, 14705, 14747, 14752, 14709, 14753, 14708, 14707, 1573, 15719, 1571, 15711, 15738, 1580000000739, 158000000074, 1580000000741, 15704, 15707, 15709, 1572, 156084666070600004701, 1560846660805, 15705, 16708, 16728, 16711, 16724, 16732, 16726, 1671, 16725, 16744, 1680000000731, 16721, 16701, 16709, 16733, 16716, 16705, 1674100012201, 16704, 16729, 16703, 16734, 16727, 16713, 1672, 17714, 17703, 17702, 17718, 1760526660703, 1760526660802, 1780526660722, 17712, 178000000072, 18601066607074, 18601066608073, 1880000000719, 18709, 1860806660702, 186080666070300013201, 18702, 1871, 18711, 1860346660714, 1860346660813, 1860266660752, 1860266660851, 18706, 1860746660711, 186074666071200013101, 1880000000714, 18713, 1880000000726, 19701, 19702, 19703, 19704, 19705, 19707, 19711, 19712, 19713, 1980000000714, 1980000000733, 19736, 1980000000734, 1980000000738, 1980000000737, 1980000000731, 1980000000736, 1980000000739, 1980000000742, 19727, 198000000072, 1980000000721, 1980000000735, 19739, 1980000000732, 1960026660801, 1980000000741, 1980000000743, 1960226660705, 196022666070600013301, 1960226660707, 19731, 1980000000728, 198000000074, 1980000000727, 1973, 19734, 19735, 198000000073, 19732, 1980000000729, 19737, 208000000071, 20708, 20704, 20705, 20706, 20707, 2071, 218000000074, 2171, 2160016660702, 2160016660801, 21703, 21704, 21701, 21705, 21706, 21726, 
              21733, 21714, 21724, 21728, 226017666070200014001, 22725, 22728, 22716, 2260176660801, 22701, 22719, 22722, 22707, 22718, 22729, 2273, 22708, 22709, 22702, 22704, 2280000000737, 23756, 23779, 23788, 23781, 23759, 23705, 23748, 23749, 23784, 23786, 23782, 23785, 23704, 23712, 237121, 23752, 23764, 2379, 23701, 2376, 23751, 23761, 23714, 23789, 23715, 2360816660815, 2372, 2378, 23711, 23765, 23757, 23783, 2375, 23799, 23776, 23721, 237441, 2480000000709991, 2460696660801, 2480000000727, 24726, 24711, 2460556660801, 248000000073, 2480626660726, 2460586660817, 24701, 24702, 24703, 24704, 24705, 2471, 24712, 24713, 24714, 2460816660801, 24725, 25718, 25741, 25736, 25742, 25724, 25734, 25729, 25726, 25743, 25722, 2580000000735, 25714, 25703, 2580000000731, 2574, 25702, 25713, 25723, 25727, 25745, 25746,  25716, 25735, 25705, 25719, 2580000000737, 258001666071, 25701, 25709, 25717, 25721, 25715, 258000000074, 25744, 2580000000741, 25725, 2580000000736, 2572, 2560826660701, 256082666070300014601, 2560826660801, 2674, 26713, 26717, 26711, 26705, 26715, 26722, 26701, 26703, 26706, 26708, 26702, 2671, 2660396660855, 26724,  2673, 26709, 26728, 26731, 2780000000706, 278000000074, 2780000000708, 27711, 2780000000738, 2780000000709, 2780000000737, 27701, 2780000000704, 278000000070991, 28704, 28707, 2871, 28711, 28712, 28715, 28714, 28713, 29709, 2971, 2973400014802, 29704, 298000000073, 29714, 30701, 30708, 30709, 30705, 30706, 30703, 31707, 31705, 31708, 31714, 31704, 31713, 316006666070200015701, 3160066660801, 316003666070300015601, 3160036660802, 31718, 31719, 31716, 31712, 31702, 3171, 31706, 32709, 3280000000713, 32706, 3280000000716, 3271300015901, 32708, 32702, 32707, 327071, 327073, 3280000000714, 32701, 32715, 32716, 3280000000715, 33703, 33702, 33704, 33726, 3372, 33762, 33729, 3380316660702, 3380316660704, 3376, 33774, 33707, 33756, 33751, 33737, 33735, 33755, 33701, 33718, 33749, 33764, 33721, 3373, 33731, 33742, 3374, 3371, 3360366660703, 3360366660801, 
              3360166660801, 33723, 33728, 33715, 33712, 33724, 33709, 33754, 33717, 33741, 33719, 34761, 34723, 34791, 347447, 3479997, 34789, 34746, 34732, 34713, 34603966608076, 34603966608074, 34603966607075, 34603966607077, 34603966607078, 3478, 34772, 34769, 34745, 34711, 3460966660801, 347101, 34716, 34754, 34724, 34736, 34782, 34722, 34704, 3471, 3471994, 34756, 347993, 34779, 34771, 347102, 34751, 347103, 34719, 34786, 34787, 3476, 34776, 34717, 34784, 34766, 34767, 34729, 34747, 34702, 34798, 34742, 34783, 34788, 34738, 34768, 34734, 34727, 3471991, 3479996, 347446, 34703, 34796, 34785, 34753, 34715, 34718, 34758, 3480466660791111, 34755, 347992, 35701, 35702, 35703, 3580000000717, 3580456660714, 3580000000713, 3580000000715, 35713, 3580000000716, 35712, 3680000000754, 36737, 3671, 36728, 36725, 36731, 3680000000742, 36723, 36736, 366015666070200016401, 3660156660801, 36727, 3680000000741, 36717, 36732, 36703, 36729, 36735, 36702, 3673, 36706, 36734, 36716, 36718, 36733, 36738, 3680000000739, 37743, 37706, 37724, 3780000000749, 3760096660709, 3760096660808, 37717, 3780000000791, 37728, 37731, 37701, 37725, 3780000000747, 37735, 37708, 10003586, 3780000000748, 37718, 37745, 37709, 3780000000761, 37707, 37729, 37738, 3772, 37721, 378000000076, 37723, 3780000000793, 3760556660701, 376055666070100016908, 37712, 37714, 37716, 37785, 37786, 37787, 3780000000755, 3780000000789, 3780000000792, 37702, 3780000000758, 37704, 37726, 37727, 3780000000754, 37788, 37742, 378000000075, 38765, 38719, 38722, 38763, 38721, 38716, 3872, 38701, 3860366660702, 3860366660801, 38705, 38723, 38764, 39777, 39778, 39701, 39702, 39703, 39704, 39705, 39706, 39707, 39708, 39709, 39711, 39713, 39714, 39718, 39719, 3972, 39722, 39723, 39724, 39727, 39728, 39729, 3973, 39731, 39732, 39733, 39734, 39735, 39736, 39737, 39738, 39739, 3974, 39741, 39775, 3980000000742, 39742, 39766, 39776, 3960426660702, 3960426660801, 3960606660704, 3960606660803, 3960116660702, 3960116660801, 39763, 
              3960546660728, 3960546660827, 39771, 3980000000757, 3980000000787, 3980356660765, 3977, 39800000007768, 3980000000794, 3980000000788, 3960646660704, 3960646660704000177, 396064666070500017701, 39769, 3960606660828, 3960606660829, 396060666083, 39779, 40702, 40703, 40704, 40708, 40709, 4071, 40705, 4071300017801, 4160356660703, 416035666070400018101, 41702, 41708, 41709, 41713, 41736, 416019666070300017901, 4160196660802, 41734, 4160256660702, 4160256660801, 41738, 41701, 41717, 41728, 41748, 41716, 42701, 42703, 42704, 4280000000705, 4270800017902, 4270700017901, 4260676660801, 4270800018001, 4380000000723, 4360796660715, 43607966608142, 43702, 43703, 43704, 43705, 43713, 43716, 43719, 4372, 43721, 43722, 43724, 4380000000735, 4380000000737, 44752, 44729, 44778, 44706, 4460716660708, 446071666070900018902, 44607166608076, 4460116660702, 4460116660801, 446123666071700019101, 4461236660814, 4461236660815, 4461236660816, 44762, 4475, 4481146660702, 4461146660701, 4461146660803, 44799987, 44703, 44781, 4480000000736, 4480000000799967, 448000000078092, 4480000000799952, 4477, 4460216660801, 44701999, 44764, 44783, 44759, 448000000078032, 44731, 44774, 44800000007994, 4479994, 44746, 4480486660701, 44775, 4462206660714, 4462206660813, 44800000007996, 4462206660811, 44723, 44709, 44721, 44733, 4479998, 44814766607918, 448000000078041, 44756, 4480000000798005, 44756, 44772, 44758, 44798004, 44705, 44711, 44712, 44715, 44716, 44757,  4476, 44766, 44767, 44769, 44777, 44779, 44782, 44785, 44787, 44788, 44789, 44791, 44793, 44794, 44795, 44796, 44798001, 44798003, 4479995, 44799961, 44799962, 44799963, 4480000000737, 44800000007993, 448000000079996, 448000000079997, 448000000079999, 4480000000799992, 44800000007998, 44799991, 44761, 4480000000799995, 44765, 4480000000738, 44753, 44755, 4480000000792, 4480000000799885, 44714, 4479993, 440000000776, 44732, 44713, 4480000000741, 44725, 44726, 44784, 4472, 44749, 4481956660701, 44800000007802, 44797, 44808566607511, 
              44824566607914, 44717, 44724, 44707, 44708, 44727, 44771, 44799992, 44768, 4460716660701, 4460576660818, 4473, 448000000079991, 44704, 4480000000799993, 44748, 44719, 44745, 4460196660723, 4460196660822, 4461496660713, 4461496660812, 4480000000739, 44773, 44734, 4580000000714, 45706, 45712, 4580186660701, 46705, 46701, 46702, 46704, 46706, 46707, 46708, 4671, 47794, 47792, 476124666071, 476124666071100020401, 478000000079, 4760536660712, 476053666071300020501, 4761246660709, 4761246660809, 47703, 47705, 47706, 47707, 47708, 47709, 4771, 47711, 47714, 47716, 47717, 4772, 47721, 47724, 47728, 4773, 47731, 47732, 47733, 47736, 47738, 47739, 4774, 47743, 47744, 47745, 47747, 47749, 477491, 4775, 47751, 47754, 47755, 47756, 47757, 47758, 47759, 4776, 47761, 47762, 47763, 477631, 47764, 47765, 47766, 47767, 47768, 47773, 47774, 47775, 47784, 47785, 47786, 47787, 4779, 4780000000785, 48722, 48781, 48706, 48705, 48713, 48707, 48732, 48711, 48726, 48703, 48714, 48777, 48704, 48779, 4960326660807, 4960416660709, 4960416660808, 4960396660708, 496039666071, 496039666071100021001, 4960116660709, 496011666071000020901, 4960316660801, 49714, 49713, 49719, 4960246660713, 496024666071400021101, 49718, 49716, 49703, 50707, 50739, 50743, 50704, 50703, 50702, 50714, 50715, 50716, 50718, 5060396660717, 5060396660816, 50738, 50747, 50733, 50723, 51704, 5170500021501, 51701)
```

Then it is a `numeric` vector:

```r
class(myid_num)
#R> [1] numeric
```

The largest figure in the array is:

```r
max(myid_num)
#R> [1] 496039666071099998208
```

which I suspect comes from 496039666071100021001. This is easy to verify:

```r
496039666071100021001
#R> [1] 496039666071099998208
```

> And how can I prevent it?

A solution is to work with characters:

```r
"496039666071100021001"
#R> [1] "496039666071100021001"
```

Or use some special package. Maybe have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r).

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very helpful!!

Comment: Happy to help. I hope it answered your question. If so, feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).